# Generating Norwegian National Identification Numbers in Python

Tags: python, beginner

I've written some Python-code to generate the [Norwegian National Identification Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Norway).

Being fairly new to Python, I'd really appreciate a review on this code in regards to best practices and style.

```
import calendar

def is_valid_date(d):
    dd,mm,yyyy = [int(i) for i in [d[:2],d[2:4],d[4:]]]
    days = {
        1: 31, 2: 29 if calendar.isleap(yyyy) else 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30, 7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31
    }

    if yyyy < 1900 or yyyy > 2039: return False
    if mm < 1 or mm > 12: return False
    if dd < 1 or dd > days[mm]: return False

    return True


def get_range(year):
    if year >= 1990 and year <= 1999: return range(500)
    if year >= 2000 and year <= 2039: return range(500,1000)
    return range(0)


def pad(n):
    return '{:03}'.format(n) if n < 100 else n

def generate(d):
    if type(d) is not str or is_valid_date(d) != True:
        raise ValueError('Expected a valid date-string with the form: ddmmyyyy')

    year, dt = int(d[4:]), [int(i) for i in d]
    for i in get_range(year):
        n = map(int,list(str(pad(i))))
        k1 = 11 - ((3*dt[0] + 7*dt[1] + 6*dt[2] + 1*dt[3] + 8*dt[-2] + 9*dt[-1] + 4*n[0] + 5*n[1] + 2*n[2]) % 11)
        k2 = 11 - ((5*dt[0] + 4*dt[1] + 3*dt[2] + 2*dt[3] + 7*dt[-2] + 6*dt[-1] + 5*n[0] + 4*n[1] + 3*n[2] + 2*k1) % 11)
        if k1 < 10 and k2 < 10: 
            print ''.join(map(str,dt[:4] + dt[6:] + n + [k1,k2]))


generate('31101990')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I only started Python about 3 months ago, so take my advice with a grain of salt.**

(also my first review here :)

## PEP8

Try to follow the PEP8 styleguide. Most of the issues I have with this are some whitespace issues. For example:

- Two empty lines between `import calendar` and `def is_valid_date(d):`
- Two empty lines between `def pad(n):` and `def generate(d):`
- Put some whitespace between variable declaration and operators for increased readability. See `dd, mm, yyyy = [int(i) for i in [d[:2],d[2:4],d[4:]]]`
- Most variable names in the functions don't really have descriptive names. For example `d` of the `is_valid_date` or `generate`
- Try not to put `if`-statements on a single line. (Not sure if this is PEP8, but still a good practice).
- None of your functions have `docstrings`. Documenting your code is great if you need to modify the code later on. Try not to reiterate how the function does something (e.g. explaining the code - that's what the code is for), but rather on ***why*** you chose to make this function.

## Now on to actual code.

- The `days` dictionary of the `is_valid_date` function is not being modified. Rather than creating it every time the method is called, perhaps consider making it a global variable, and making it more readable:

```py
days = {
    1: 31,
    2: 29 if calendar.isleap(yyyy) else 28,
    3: 31,
    4: 30,
    5: 31,
    6: 30,
    7: 31,
    8: 31,
    9: 30,
    10: 31,
    11: 30,
    12: 31
}

def is_valid_date(date):
    ...
```

However another way of doing this, is by using the already imported `calendar` module. This has the function [`calendar.monthrange(year, month)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange), which also returns the number of days in the given month. This automatically takes care of leap years or other irregularities. Be wary that this returns 2 values though. To return only the amount of days in a month, you could use `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]`.

- In `pad(n)` you return either a formatted string, or a number. This means the there are two return types. You could have it return a string always:

```py
def pad(n):
    return '{:03}'.format(n) if n < 100 else str(n)
```

or

```py
def pad(n):
    n = str(n)
    if n < 100:
        return n.zfill(3)
    return n
```

which makes it a bit more readable. However, the pad function is not necessary, as the `string.zfill(width)` function can take of that for you:

```py
>>>'75'.zfill(3)
'075'
>>>'655'.zfill(3)
'655'
>>>'{:03}'.format(75)
'075'
>>>'{:03}'.format(655)
```

Both functions only pad if necessary. This means you can do `str(n).zfill(3)` instead of the entire pad function.

- In `generate(d)`, your string type check is not python2 and 3 compatible. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843173/how-to-check-if-type-of-a-variable-is-string) link for a better answer on string type checking.
- The first line of the `generate(d)` function check for `!= True`. As `is_valid_date` already returns a boolean value, using `not` would be a better choice:

```py
def generate(d):
    if not isstring(d) or not is_valid_date(d):
        raise ValueError('Expected date string in format ddmmyyy, but got {}'.format(d))
```

---

Some more!

In `get_range(year)` you use

```py
if year >= 1990 and year <= 1999:
    return range(500)
```

but this can also be written as:

```py
if 1990 <= year <= 1999:
    return range(500)
```

or even:

```py
if year in range(1990, 2000):  # more 'human' like. 
    return range(500)
```

... which are both slightly more succinct. The first option (interval comparison) can also be applied in the `is_valid_date` function:

```py
if 1900 > yyyy > 2039:
    return False
if 1 > mm > 12:
    return False
if 1 > dd > calendar.monthrange(yyyy, mm)[1]:
    return False
```

---

Another completely different direction you could go into, is converting the given date string to a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object:

```py
from datetime import datetime

birthdate = datetime.strptime('%d%m%Y', datestring)
```

A nice bonus that comes with this, is that date validation is already done, as it will throw a `ValueError` if it's given an invalid date, thus eliminating the entire `is_valid_date` function.

This answer is already long enough, so I will keep it at that :)

Comment: Good job on your first answer :) !

Answer (score 3):

I would like to comment on this block of code:

```
    k1 = 11 - ((3*dt[0] + 7*dt[1] + 6*dt[2] + 1*dt[3] + 8*dt[-2] + 9*dt[-1] + 4*n[0] + 5*n[1] + 2*n[2]) % 11)
    k2 = 11 - ((5*dt[0] + 4*dt[1] + 3*dt[2] + 2*dt[3] + 7*dt[-2] + 6*dt[-1] + 5*n[0] + 4*n[1] + 3*n[2] + 2*k1) % 11)
    if k1 < 10 and k2 < 10: 
        print ''.join(map(str,dt[:4] + dt[6:] + n + [k1,k2]))
```

The lines `k1 =` and `k2 =` are very complex, so you should add a link to the technical document from which this calculations were taken.

The `if` makes the function fail silently if the calculations are wrong and the result is not a single digit, better fail with an error message.

The `print` makes this function single purpose, `return` would allow re-use inside a bigger program.